# Перемешивание вопросов с определенными кнопками в Телеграм боте

Tags: python, telebot

Опять-же столкнулся с данной проблемой: хочу реализовать в телеграм боте систему перемешивания вопросов с определенными на них ответами, но у меня не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random

token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
spes = ["Сколько время", "Когда домой?"]
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = random.choice(spes))
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def rf(message):
    if bot.message == "Сколько время":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        k1 = types.KeyboardButton('хз')
        k2 = types.KeyboardButton('Тоже хз')
        markup.add(k1, k2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'wergwergh', reply_markup=markup)
def rf1(message):
    if message.text == 'хз':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ага")
    elif message.text == 'Тоже хз':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Да")
```

bot.polling()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я протестировал Ваше решение. Вот возможное решение проблемы:

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random

token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
spes = ["Сколько время", "Когда домой?"]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    question = random.choice(spes)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=question)
    if question == "Сколько время":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        k1 = types.KeyboardButton('хз')
        k2 = types.KeyboardButton('Тоже хз')
        markup.add(k1, k2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'wergwergh', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def rf1(message):
    if message.text == 'хз':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ага")
    elif message.text == 'Тоже хз':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Да")

bot.polling()
```

`bot.message` не существует для проверки, хоть и `message.text` таким образом не реализуешь. Поэтому слегка подправил общую структуру Вашего кода, без использования фукнции `rf`.

Успехов в Ваших проектах :)